# Azure queue trigger duplicate value

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-queues

I have Azure Queue in operation that I write to after each execution on a azure time trigger.The time trigger added message to the queue. But in some times  duplicate value added in azure queue. The queue trigger functionality is to send notifications to user in a particular time. But some time user get 3 notification.

In time tigger execute in 15 min interval. When the time trigger execute in 11.45Am, the user get notifications total 3.
At time 11.45Am, 11.50am, 11.55am etc. But actually we need to send only one notification in 11.45 am. I cheked the time trigger log, it execute only in 15 time interval.

```
public void AddToQueue(string queueData, string name, string connectionString)
    {
        //"DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=myAccount;AccountKey=c3RyaW5nIGxlbmd0aCB2YWxpZA=="
        var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString);
        var queueClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudQueueClient();
        var queue = queueClient.GetQueueReference(name);
        queue.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();
        var message = new CloudQueueMessage(queueData);
        queue.AddMessageAsync(message);
    }
```

Is any dulicate added in queue or any issue in my code?
Note: total I have 3 queue trigger functions and one time trigger function.

Comment: The only thing suspicious I see is using Async method without `await` and `async Task` as method return type. Also, can you confirm whether the 3 notifications is from one same queue message or not?

Comment: yes,I noticed that the issue found when I push aprox.900 data to the queue at a time. When push 100 or 400 data, no issue, working it's fine. Problem not found in all time.